# How can the Fourier delta function produce different matrices in single-pixel imaging?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, signal-processing, imaging

The pattern in the masks used for single-pixel imaging are created applying equation $(1)$,

$$P_\phi (x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ 1 +| F^{-1} \{\delta_H (u,v) e^{i\phi}\}|\right], \tag{1}$$

in which the Fourier delta function with centre points $(u_0, v_0) = (0,0)$ is

$$\delta_H (u,v) = \begin{cases}
1 & u=u_0\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,v=v_0 \tag{2}\\ 0 &\mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Considering that each mask is a different $n \times n$ square matrix and that the centre points are constant, wouldn't this result in the production of the same mask/matrix over and over again?

**How can different patterns, $P_\phi$, be created if the delta function, $\delta_H$, presents a value of $0$ at all points except the centre?**

---

This is based on the following [article](https://doi.org/10.1364/OE.25.019619) and related to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160049/).

Comment: The article and Mathematics question are both about Hadamard transforms, not Fourier transforms.  Regardless, I am not sure I understand your question.  Are you saying Matlab gives you a different mask each time you run this algorithm on the same signal?  If so, I think something is wrong in your code because FFTs are perfectly reversible/invertible.

Comment: I intend to create a square matrix with all the values from the delta function, but I don't know how to do this.

And are there any differences between the Hadamard and the Fourier transform? Wherever I look the conditions seem to be the same.

Comment: A delta function just gives you the value of the function at the argument of the delta function when integrated (i.e., as is done in Fourier transforms).  It's actually a really convenient operator because it makes almost any integral possible and very easy.  Regardless, you can look up how to construct a white noise spectrum get some constant Fourier coefficients/amplitudes and then apply the delta function in frequency space.  Or you can apply the delta function in time-space and then FT it to get the only surviving coeffs.  Either way should work.